# Why does rebasing unset my current branch and does not complete?

Tags: git, rebase

I'm on branch b4 and do "$ git rebase master", it gives me conflicts.

```
 $ git rebase master
    First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
    Applying: rebase: Modified 1.txt
    Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
    M       1.txt
    Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
    Auto-merging 1.txt
    CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in 1.txt
    Failed to merge in the changes.
    Patch failed at 0001 rebase: Modified 1.txt
    The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
       c:/hands_on/github/learn_git/cmd/.git/rebase-apply/patch

    When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
    If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
    To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Here, it shows that I'm NO longer on branch b4.

```
 $ git status
    # Not currently on any branch.
    # You are currently rebasing.
    #   (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
    #   (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
    #   (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)
    #
    # Unmerged paths:
    #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    #   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    #
    #       both modified:      1.txt
    #
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I fixed conflicts and committed the changes:

```
$ vim 1.txt

$ git commit -a -m "Fixed rebase conflict"
[detached HEAD 2cb2672] Fixed rebase conflict
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# You are currently rebasing.
#   (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But when I tried "--continue", it does not complete rebase, but instead giving me more "instructions". Why?

```
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: rebase: Modified 1.txt
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I fixed conflicts and committed the changes:

That's where you went wrong. `git rebase --continue` expects the changes to be in the index, but not yet committed. Since you already committed the changes, `git rebase`'s own attempt fails, because there are no changes left to be committed.

You should be able to undo your commit action, without resetting the index, by running `git reset --soft @^`. And `git rebase --continue` should work after that.

You could alternatively use `git rebase --skip` to bypass `git rebase`'s own attempt to commit the changes, but this risks a bit more getting messed up: your own commit will most likely not have respected the original commit's author name, email and time.

The fact that `git status` shows you're not on any branch is not a problem. `git rebase` intentionally detaches from the current branch until the operation finishes. This will be fixed up after the operations have succeeded.